# Long Breakeven inflation

Tags: portfolio-management, yield, inflation, treasuries

I want to go long bei by going long individual 10 year tips and short individual 10 year treasuries. How do I calculate and match the duration?

Answer (score 1):

*"In order to setup a breakeven trade, one needs to make an assumption about the beta between real yields and  nominal yields. Typically investors assume a beta of 1 however this could be changed based on historical relationships. In a breakeven trade with an assumed beta of 1, the risk weights are a function of the relative DV01 of the linker and nominal comparator bond"* - JPM Inflation Linked Markets Guide 2017

My guess is most people would not "calculate" duration (or DV01) but rather just pull it up on Bloomberg or Eikon.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have access to either

Comment: DV01s for OTRs here: https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/treasury-analytics.html#